# Delete users on Ubuntu Core

Tags: ssh, password, users, delete, ubuntu-core

I created a user on my Ubuntu Core distribution with ssh key and without password. But a few days later, Ubuntu ask me a password to connect (even if I didn't specify a password before). So to continue to use my device, I had to create a new account. With that account, I tried to delete the first one with the command: 
```sudo /usr/sbin/deluser k-ber````

Unfortunately, the command didn't work and the result was: `userdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later`

Have you a solution to avoid the problem of password and solve the problem of deleting users?

Many thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Logon-asking-for-a-password on a SSH-key-only system is a classic symptom of a wrong username. On Ubuntu Core, this is often folks forgetting to use their Ubuntu One login name. ("*Oops, I put `ssh fred@core1` instead of `ssh fred-foo@core1`*")

Comment: Yes I agree with that. Most of the time, this is the reason. But here, I verified twice my login name to avoid this mistake. So I tried with the right name and the associate key and it stills ask me a password...